# Could not initialize class com.rsa.cryptoj.o.pg null

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have applied CF10 Update 14 to my production stack and have had numerous reports of applications failing.  Most of them have the error "Could not initialize class com.rsa.cryptoj.o.pg null" in their log files.

The servers are setup for sandboxing so there are multiple sites hosted on each server.  Some research indicates to disable sandbox security.  This is not an option for my situation.  Can anyone point me into another direction for a possible solution?  I'm considering uninstalling update 14 to verify it is indeed the culprit.

Thank you.

Comment: This might be the disabling of SSL3 by default. Did you reinstall/upgrade the connectors?

Comment: Our team has seen evidence of this bug since Update 12.

Comment: Ok ... here's a wild guess from wil. "it may be an issue with running the JRE instead of the JDK
[5:02:31 PM] Wil Genovese: which Java version?
[5:02:39 PM] Wil Genovese: theres something different with Java 1.7
[5:03:01 PM] Wil Genovese: In the startup (server.log) does he see this?  Unable to initialise Cryptograpic service: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: See the comments in this post: http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-10-update-8-is-now-available-java-7-support-included

Comment: Hi Mark - Thanks for the guidance.  I have since uninstalled CF10u14 and rolled back to update12.  All seems well.  I'm attempting to narrow down what is going on in update14 that would cause this mess.  I'll report back with my findings to help work toward a solution.

Comment: I have updated the JRE to 1.8 and installed CF update 15.  Regardless, this error still exists.

Answer (score 2):

After digging and digging, I found this entry:

http://www.mischefamily.com/nathan/index.cfm/2010/4/16/OpenID-And-ColdFusion

Disabling the RSA libraries solved this problem.  Within the CF admin, within each sandbox, I modified the JVM arguments from `-Dcoldfusion.jsafe.defaultalgo=FIPS186Random` to `-Dcoldfusion.disablejsafe=true`.  My sites/company does not require FIPS 140 compliance.  Because of this, the modification resolved the error.

Answer (score 0):

After applying update 17, we start getting "Could not initialize class com.rsa.cryptoj.o.pg null" in the logs. And our CF administrator update page was broken. We uninstall and reinstall update 17 and we no longer get this error and our CF administrator update page works. 
See https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3918827 for more details.